# Share data from one component with another component in same App.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have the following App.js file that runs on WebSphere.  I just added a new component that needs a value from the same API the larger component uses.  I don't want to hit the API twice.  I'm thinking I need to move the data access into the new Vue({… and then pass the result into the two components.  How do I do that?  Can someone point me to sample code?

```
Vue.component('greeting-portlet-text', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      today: '',
      bonusPageLink: '/wps/myportal/k/payroll/bonus'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getFormattedTodaysDate: function() {
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
      return today;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.today = this.getFormattedTodaysDate();
  },
  template:
    '<div class="greeting-text"><h1>Welcome ' +
    _greentin_app_config.user.firstName +
    '</h1>' +
    '  <p class="subtitle">Your bonus progress as of {{ today }}</p> ' +
    '  <div class="greeting-buttons greeting-buttons-top show-for-large">' + 
    '    <greeting-portlet-buttons></greeting-portlet-buttons>' +
    '    <a :href="bonusPageLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent highlight">View Full Bonus Progress</a>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '</div>'
});

Vue.component('greeting-portlet-buttons-panel', {
    data: function() {
      return {
          bonusPageLink: '/wps/myportal/k/payroll/bonus'
      };
    },
    template:
      '<div class="greeting-buttons greeting-buttons-bottom grid-x grid-margin-x">' +
      '  <div class="cell small-12 medium-6">' + 
      '    <greeting-portlet-buttons></greeting-portlet-buttons>' +
      '  </div>' + 
      '  <div class="cell small-12 medium-6"><a :href="bonusPageLink" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent highlight">View Full Bonus Progress</a></div>' +
      '</div>'
});

Vue.component('greeting-portlet-buttons', {
    data: function() {
        return {
              SmartDriveLink: '/wps/myportal/k/company-info/news/smartdrivefaq'
            };
    },
    template:
      '<div>' +
      '    <a v-if="SmartDriveScore>=25 && SmartDriveScore!=99999" :href="SmartDriveLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--red-A700 mdl-color-text--white">SmartDrive Score:&nbsp;&nbsp; {{SmartDriveScore}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">thumb_down_alt</i></a>' +
      '    <a v-if="SmartDriveScore=== 99999" :href="SmartDriveLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--yellow">SmartDrive Score:&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">phone_in_talk</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;CALL DDM</a>' + 
      '    <a v-if="SmartDriveScore<25" :href="SmartDriveLink" class="button expanded mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--green mdl-color-text--white">SmartDrive Score:&nbsp;&nbsp; {{SmartDriveScore}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">thumb_up_alt</i></a>' +
      '</div>'
});

Vue.component('greeting-portlet-progress', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      bonus: {
        payBand: {
          showPayBand: false // default
        },
        milageTiers: {
          tier1: 0,
          tier2: 0,
          tier3: 0,
          tier4: 0
        },
        rateTiers: {
          tier1: 0,
          tier2: 0,
          tier3: 0,
          tier4: 0
        },
        currentMileage: 872
      },
      viewStatus: {
        dataLoaded: false
      },
      storageKey: 'bonusProgressData'
    };
  },
  computed: {
    tier1Miles: function() {
      return this.formatNumber(this.bonus.milageTiers.tier1);
    },
    tier2Miles: function() {
      return this.formatNumber(this.bonus.milageTiers.tier2);
    },
    tier3Miles: function() {
      return this.formatNumber(this.bonus.milageTiers.tier3);
    },
    tier4Miles: function() {
      return this.formatNumber(this.bonus.milageTiers.tier4);
    },
    tier1Rate: function() {
      return '$' + this.bonus.rateTiers.tier1;
    },
    tier2Rate: function() {
      return '$' + this.bonus.rateTiers.tier2;
    },
    tier3Rate: function() {
      return '$' + this.bonus.rateTiers.tier3;
    },
    tier4Rate: function() {
      return '$' + this.bonus.rateTiers.tier4;
    },
    tier1Percentage: function() {
      return (
        Math.floor(
          (this.bonus.milageTiers.tier1 / this.bonus.milageTiers.tier4) * 100
        ) + '%'
      );
    },
    tier2Percentage: function() {
      return (
        Math.floor(
          (this.bonus.milageTiers.tier2 / this.bonus.milageTiers.tier4) * 100
        ) + '%'
      );
    },
    tier3Percentage: function() {
      return (
        Math.floor(
          (this.bonus.milageTiers.tier3 / this.bonus.milageTiers.tier4) * 100
        ) + '%'
      );
    },
    tier4Percentage: function() {
      return (
        Math.floor(
          (this.bonus.milageTiers.tier4 / this.bonus.milageTiers.tier4) * 100
        ) + '%'
      );
    },
    currentMilage: function() {
      return this.formatNumber(this.bonus.currentMileage);
    },
    progress: function() {
      return this.progressNumber + '%';
    },
    progressNumber: function() {
      var percentage = 0;
      if (
        this.bonus.currentMileage !== 0 ||
        this.bonus.milageTiers.tier4 !== 0
      ) {
        percentage = Math.floor(
          (this.bonus.currentMileage / this.bonus.milageTiers.tier4) * 100
        );
      }
      return percentage;
    },
    showPayBand: function() {
      return this.bonus.payBand.showPayBand;
    },
    payBandMiles: function() {
      return this.formatNumber(this.bonus.payBand.miles);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadBonusDataFromService: function() {
      var app = this;
      var servicePath =
        _greentin_app_config.serviceBasePath +
        '/v1/knight/portal/bonus/progress';

      axios
        .get(servicePath)
        .then(function(response) {
          app.bonus = response.data;
          app.viewStatus.dataLoaded = true;

          if (typeof storageWrap !== 'undefined') {
            // cache the data
            storageWrap.setItem(app.storageKey, app.bonus);
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },

    getBonusData: function() {
      var cachedData;

      if (typeof storageWrap !== 'undefined') {
        cachedData = storageWrap.getItem(this.storageKey);
      }

      // return cachedData if found otherwise load the data from service
      if (cachedData) {
        this.bonus = cachedData;
        this.viewStatus.dataLoaded = true;
      } else {
        this.loadBonusDataFromService();
      }
    },

    formatNumber: function(value) {
      if (typeof value !== 'number') {
        return value;
      }
      var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'decimal',
        minimumFractionDigits: 0
      });
      return formatter.format(value);
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getBonusData();
  },
  template:
    '<div>' +
    '<div v-if="viewStatus.dataLoaded" class="progress-wrapper">' +
    '<div class="progress">' +
    '<div class="progress-bar" v-bind:style="{ width: progress }">' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__label" v-if="progressNumber > 9" >{{ currentMilage }} mi.</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="progress-bar__marker" v-bind:style="{ left: tier1Percentage }">' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText">' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText__label">{{tier1Miles}}</span><br>' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText__value">{{tier1Rate}}</span>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="progress-bar__marker" v-bind:style="{ left: tier2Percentage }">' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText">' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText__label">{{tier2Miles}}</span><br>' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText__value">{{tier2Rate}}</span>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="progress-bar__marker" v-bind:style="{ left: tier3Percentage }">' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText">' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText__label">{{tier3Miles}}</span><br>' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText__value">{{tier3Rate}}</span>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="progress-bar__marker" v-bind:style="{ left: tier4Percentage }">' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText">' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText__label">{{tier4Miles}}+</span><br>' +
    '<span class="progress-bar__markerText__value">{{tier4Rate}}</span>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="payband" v-if="showPayBand">' +
    '<p class="payband__stat"><span class="payband__label">Miles to next pay increase:</span> <span class="payband__amount">{{payBandMiles}}</span></p>' +
    '<p class="payband__description"><span>* SOLO = $0.01/mi</span><span>* TEAM = $0.005/mi</span></p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
});



(window.onload = function() {
  var SmartDriveScore = 0;
  storageWrap.setAdaptor(sessionStorage); // default to session storage

  if (_greentin_app_config.displayPage === 'dashboard') {
    if (_greentin_app_config.started !== true) {
      // performance check

      _greentin_app_config.started = true; // sets performance flag

      new Vue({
        el: _greentin_app_config.targetEl,
        mounted: function() {
          this.SmartDriveScore = 99999;
        },
        template:
          '<div class="greeting-portlet">' +
          '    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">' +
          '        <div class="cell small-12 large-5"><greeting-portlet-text></greeting-portlet-text></div>' +
          '        <div class="cell small-12 large-7"><greeting-portlet-progress></greeting-portlet-progress></div>' +
          '        <div class="cell small-12 hide-for-large"><greeting-portlet-buttons-panel></greeting-portlet-buttons-panel></div>' +
          '    </div>' +
          '</div>'
      });
    }
  } else {
    new Vue({
      el: '#bonus-progress-wrapper',
      template:
        '<div class="default-view"><greeting-portlet-text></greeting-portlet-text>' +
        '<greeting-portlet-progress></greeting-portlet-progress></div>'
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: call that api in the vue instance and pass the result using props

Comment: Use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). Create store with your object, create mutation that will update the state and commit your object to the store. This object is also reactive, so when you update value in the store, it will re-render in templates. I would even put the `_greentin_app_config` into vuex store.

Comment: since `vuex` was already suggested, I'll note some other possibilities (though vuex is the best choice IMO). You could also use a `vue instance properties`, `vue bus`, `session storage`, or a `global object`